# Mixins with variable number of string arguments in D?

Tags: d, mixins

I'm working on some D bindings for an existing C library, and I have a bunch of function definitions, and a bunch of bindings for them. For example:

```
// Functions
void function(int) funcA;
long function() funcB;
bool function(bool) funcC;
char function(string) funcD;
// etc...

// Bindings
if(!presentInLibrary("func")) return false;
if(!bindFunction(funcA, "funcA")) return false;
if(!bindFunction(funcB, "funcB")) return false;
if(!bindFunction(funcC, "funcC")) return false;
if(!bindFunction(funcD, "funcD")) return false;
// etc...
```

This model is very similar to how Derelict handles OpenGL extension loading. However, this seems like a lot of redundant typing. I'd really like a way to express the "binding" portion above as something like:

```
BINDGROUP("func", "funcA", "funcB", "funcC", "funcD", ...); // Name of function group, then variable list of function names.
```

Is this something that can be done with mixins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used this when I was doing dynamic loading, while it doesn't answer your question you may be able to adapt it:

```cs
void function() a;
int function(int) b;
void function(string) c;

string bindFunctions(string[] funcs...)
{
    string ret;
    foreach (func; funcs)
    {
        ret ~= func ~ ` = cast(typeof(` ~ func ~ `))lib.getSymbol("` ~ func ~ `");`;
    }
    return ret;
}
mixin(bindFunctions("a", "b", "c"));
```

Here `bindFunctions("a", "b", "c")` returns a string that looks something like:

```cs
a = cast(typeof(a))lib.getSymbol("a");
b = cast(typeof(b))lib.getSymbol("b");
c = cast(typeof(c))lib.getSymbol("c");
```

Where `lib.getSymbol()` returns a pointer from `dl_open()` etc. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd have to poke at it, but I think you should be able to make this work without the string mix-in by using static foreach in a normal fuction. You might need to use a template mix-in to get things to bind from the correct scope.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you meant string mixins? You can just make straight-forward use of D's vararg syntax:

```
string BINDGROUP(string functionGroup, string[] functions...)
{
    // ...
}

mixin(BINDGROUP("func", "funcA", "funcB", "funcC", "funcD"));
```

Comment: I was under the impression that this wouldn't work because the strings had to be known at compile-time, and having a string vararg breaks that. If that's not the case, I'd definitely do this! (Also, yes, I meant string mixins, thanks you for the clarification).

Comment: @mark the compiler will attempt to calculate weakly pure functions at compile time if the result is needed to finish compilation (with `enum` or `mixin`) and throw an error when it can't be calculated. besides varargs (and template args in general) are expanded at compile time when instantiated

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is what you're looking for

```
template BINDGROUP(string group,T...){
    alias BINDGROUP presentInLibrary("func") && BINDGROUPFUNCS!(T);
}

template BINDGROUPFUNCS(T...){
    static if(T.length)alias BINDGROUPFUNCS true; // all is successful
    else alias BINDGROUPFUNCS bindFunction(mixin(T), T) && BINDGROUPFuncts!(T[1..$]);
}
```

I'm using recursive template declaration here, you could also do this with foreach loops